# Improve speed of an optimization problem

Tags: python, scipy

I have the following app that optimize the following pb. The code works but i found it a little bit slow. Any idea of performance improvements ( without writing c code ) that can be done to better use python, numpy and scipy? It seems me that the interpolate function is the main time consuming part.

```
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import timeit


class Bond(object):
  def __init__(self, years, cpn):
    self.years = years 
    self.coupon = cpn
    self.cashflows = [(0.0, -1.0)]
    self.cashflows.extend([(float(i),self.coupon) for i in range(1,self.years)])
    self.cashflows.append((float(self.years), 1.0 + self.coupon))

  def pv(self, market):
    return sum([cf[1] * market.df(cf[0]) for cf in self.cashflows])

class Market(object):
  def __init__(self, instruments):
    self.instruments = sorted(
        instruments, key=lambda instrument : instrument.cashflows[-1][0])
    self.knots = [0.0]
    self.knots.extend([inst.cashflows[-1][0] for inst in self.instruments])
    self.dfs = [1.0]
    self.dfs.extend([1.0] * len(self.instruments))
    self.interp = interp1d(self.knots, self.dfs)

  def df(self, day):
    return self.interp(day)

  def calibrate(self):
    leastsq(self.__target, self.dfs[1:])

  def __target(self, x):
    self.dfs[1:] = x
    self.interp = interp1d(self.knots, self.dfs)
    return [bond.pv(self) for bond in self.instruments]


def main():
  instruments = [Bond(i, 0.02) for i in xrange(1, numberOfInstruments + 1)]
  market = Market(instruments)
  market.calibrate()
  print('CALIBRATED')

numberOfTimes = 10
numberOfInstruments = 50
print('%.2f' % float(timeit.timeit(main, number=numberOfTimes)/numberOfTimes))
```

Comment: one more things to notice is for example once the model has been calibrated, if i call calibrate once again it takes 4s for the function to complete ! I would have thought that the optimizer stops at first step.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to vectorize the summations and the calls to the interpolation routine. For example, like this:

```
import numpy as np

class Bond(object):
  def __init__(self, years, cpn):
    self.years = years
    self.coupon = cpn

    self.cashflows = np.zeros((self.years + 1, 2))
    self.cashflows[:,0] = np.arange(self.years + 1)
    self.cashflows[:,1] = self.coupon
    self.cashflows[0,:] = 0, -1
    self.cashflows[-1,:] = self.years, 1.0 + self.coupon

  def pv(self, market):
    return (self.cashflows[:,1] * market.df(self.cashflows[:,0])).sum()
```

which seems to give a ~ 10x speedup. You can also replace the `knots` and `dfs` lists in `Market` with arrays in a similar way.

The reason why the re-calibration takes time, is that `leastsq` has to verify again that it really sits at a local minimum. This requires numerical differentiation of the target function, which does take time, as you have many free variables. The optimization problem is fairly easy, so it converges in a few steps, which means verification of the minimum takes nearly as much time as solving the problem.

Comment: It gives me a great improvement ( ~20x ) . Great sol. But i don't get the other hint you gave me about changing knots and dfs with arrays. Which part there could be vectorize (except the structure itself )?

Answer (score 0):

@pv's answer is most likely right, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295799/how-to-improve-performance-of-this-code/4299378#4299378) shows a simple way to be sure, and to show if there is anything further you could do.